# Multiple optional query parameters but requiring at least one of them to be provided .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating an endpoint that has 3 params. One param is required and in the route. The other 2 parameters are query parameters and at least one of them needs to be provided. Not sure how to go about doing this in .NET core.

```
[HttpGet("{source}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get(
    string source, 
    [FromQuery] string year, 
    [FromQuery] string genre)
{
}
```

I saw model binding. Will I need to build a model and do model validation? I can obviously add custom logic to the controller to check but I have a feeling there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Here's an example of implementing your own `IActionConstraint` that allows you to mark query parameters as required through an attribute: https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/required-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Check for the optional parameters and validate accordingly

```
[HttpGet("{source}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get(
    string source, 
    [FromQuery] string year, 
    [FromQuery] string genre) {

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(year) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(genre))
        return BadRequest();

    //...
}
```

Other wise you would need a custom filter that checks for the query strings

```
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public class ValidateQueryStringStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {

        var query = context.Request.Query;

        if(!query.ContainsKey("year") && !query.ContainsKey("genre"))
            context.ModelState.AddModelError("", "At least year or genre required");

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid) {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys) {
                result.Add(key, String.Join(", ", context.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(p => p.ErrorMessage)));
            }

            // 400 - Bad Request
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(result) { StatusCode = 400 };
        }
    }
}
```

And used on the action

```
[HttpGet("{source}")]
[ValidateQueryStringState]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get(
    string source, 
    [FromQuery] string year, 
    [FromQuery] string genre) {        

    //...

}
```